# What is meant by "No tensor may be expressed as a single tensor product"?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

My book about Nonlinear Solid Mechanics contains the following sentence (also see picture below):

> Note further that no tensor may be expressed as a single tensor product, in general, $\mathbf{A} =  \mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}\otimes\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{y}\otimes\mathbf{z}$.

I can't really make sense of this, I mean, theoretically *both* $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}\otimes\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}\otimes\mathbf{z}$ should be tensors? What is this sentence trying to tell me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My best guess is that they're trying to convey the fact that sums of simple tensors need not be simple tensors (by simple tensor I mean a tensor of the form $a\otimes b$).

Comment: @MichaelMorrow So it could mean that not every general tensor can be expressed as just a single tensor product, but every general tensor can be expressed as a sum of two of them?

Comment: It is even worse: some cannot even be expressed as the sum of two of them

Comment: (Unless the ordinary vectors you start with live in a two-dimensional space)

Comment: The point of tensors is that you not just get all the $a \otimes b$ but also all their linear combinations

Comment: That is why the space $U \otimes V$ (for linear spaces $U$ and $V$) has dimension equal to the *product* of the dimensions of $U$ and $V$ (hence is HUGE compared to the space $U \oplus V$ consisting of tuples $(u, v)$ with $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ and whose dimension is only the *sum* of the dimensions of $U$ and $V$)

Comment: they express it pourly with their 'no tensor': of course *some* tensors can be expressed in the form $x \otimes y$, for instance the tensor $x \otimes y$ itself... But what they try to convey is what Michael says: that in general not all tensors are simple tensors. The set of simple tensors is a very thin subset of a very weird geometric shape floating around in the much much bigger (and simpler looking) linear space of all tensors which is defined as the set of all linear combinatrions of simple tensors (subject to the rules about which are equal to which)

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, could easily be an answer at that point. Pretty sure the vectors are supposed to be 3d, at least they are everywhere else in the book. So with 3d vectors, is there any interpretation how $\mathbf{A} =  \mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}\otimes\mathbf{x}$ could make sense? (Book was written by an engineer, so mathematical inconsistencies are probably a possibility too.)

Comment: Here the dyadic products are used as matrices, $u\otimes v=uv^T$ (if working with the usual column vectors, the product-with-vector formula in the excerpt seems to suggest that row vectors are used as base). A simple product has rank one, the rank of a matrix gives the minimal number of terms in a sum of simple products. Thus it is not astonishing that a generic matrix has full rank, is regular. The set of rank-one matrices is then indeed a very thin set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find that a poorly worded sentence. It should say something like

> Not every tensor can be expressed as a "simple/pure tensor".

What this means is that if we take two (say real) vector spaces $U$ and $V$, then in general it is NOT true that for every $\xi\in U\otimes V$, there exist $u\in U$, and $v\in V$ such that $\xi=u\otimes v$. Said another way, such pure/simple tensors $\{u\otimes v\}_{u\in U, v\in V}$ are special things. Also, in general, the sum of pure tensors need not again be a pure tensor.

On the other hand, every tensor can be expressed as a linear combination of pure tensors. More precisely, if $\{u_1,\dots, u_n\}$ and $\{v_1,\dots, v_m\}$ are bases for $U$ and $V$ respectively, then $\{u_i\otimes v_j\,:\, 1\leq i\leq n, \,1\leq j\leq m\}$ will be a basis for the space of tensors $U\otimes V$, so for every $\xi\in U\otimes V$, there are scalars $c_{ij}$ such that
\begin{align}
\xi=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mc_{ij}u_i\otimes v_j
\end{align}